# "Corba Naming Service Not Reachable"

Tags: windows-7-x64, corba, orb, omniorb

Corba naming service is not reachable. It's running on windows XP but not on Windows7 64bit with same settings. Omninames. exe is running and log file is created however other processes are giving same error on Windows7 " Corba Naming Service Not Reachable".

It is a local machine with Visual Studio 2005 32bit and Windows7 64 bit

Comment: How are the clients provided the path to the naming service? If it is through the registry, the registry key is different on Windows 64 bit compared to XP. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16695833/resolve-initial-references-causes-a-systemexception

Comment: Hi Brian Thanks for reply. I have already applied steps mentioned in the link you provided(By placing registry in (Wow6432node) for 64 bit machine. However It is still not able to find

Comment: 1. please provide your calling code and IOR of the NamingService. 2. Have you ever tried to connect to the NamingService via corbaloc URLs?